# UITableView force sectionIndex to update without calling reloadData

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, photokit, phphotolibrary

I'm modifying my `UITableView`'s data source from a `PHChange` instance, and this works fine. What I don't understand is I can't get the sectionIndex on the right of the `UITableView` to update unless you reload the whole `UITableView` with: `reloadData`.

Is there any other way to force update the sectionIndex on the right of the `UITableView`? If I manually call: `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:` I confirm that I'm getting back fresh data, however the old sectionIndex on the right doesn't change visually, which is what I need.

Code:

```
PHFetchResultChangeDetails *changeDetails = [changeInstance changeDetailsForFetchResult:oldFetch];

if (changeDetails)
{
   PHFetchResult *fetchResultAfterChange = changeDetails.fetchResultAfterChanges;

   if (fetchResultAfterChange.count < 1)
   {
       [subArray removeObjectAtIndex:subIdx];

       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^
       {
            NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:subIdx inSection:idx];

            [self.albumsTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[path] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

            // Confirmed data is updating            
            NSLog(@"%@",[self sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:self.albumsTableView]);

            // Does nothing                    
            [self.albumsTableView setNeedsDisplay];
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this function

`- reloadSectionIndexTitles`

> This method gives you a way to update the section index after inserting or deleting sections without having to reload the whole table.

Comment: Don't know how I didn't see this in the auto code complete. Thank you!

Comment: This method is not often used.:)

Comment: It's a lifesaver method